# Horizontal Lines in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Trying to draw an 8 x 8 grid in Tkinter and I have the vertical lines drawn, but I can't seem to draw the horizontal lines correctly.

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class CanvasGrid:
def __init__(self):
    self.window = Tk()
    self.window.title("Grid")
    self.canvas = Canvas(self.window, width=128, height=128, bg="white")
    self.canvas.pack()

def displayVertical(self):
    self.canvas.create_line(16, 0, 16, 128, fill="red", tags="line")
    self.canvas.create_line(32, 0, 32, 128, fill="red", tags="line")
    self.canvas.create_line(48, 0, 48, 128, fill="red", tags="line")
    self.canvas.create_line(64, 0, 64, 128, fill="red", tags="line")
    self.canvas.create_line(80, 0, 80, 128, fill="red", tags="line")
    self.canvas.create_line(96, 0, 96, 128, fill="red", tags="line")
    self.canvas.create_line(112, 0, 112, 128, fill="red", tags="line")


def displayHorizontal(self):
    self.canvas.create_line(50, 50, 50, 50, fill="blue", tags="line")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`50 50 50 50` is a dot not a line that's why you aren't seeing it.

info:

```
canvas.create_line(startx, starty, endx, endy __then other args__)
```

try

```
canvas.create_line(0,50,widthofwindow,50
```

Answer (score 2):

As it is the same code for either direction, you can pass the start values to a function that creates either/both directions if you want.

```
class CanvasGrid:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("Grid")
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.window, width=128,
                            height=128, bg = "white")
        self.display_lines(16, 0, 16, 128, "red")
        self.display_lines(0, 16, 128, 16, "blue")
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.window.mainloop()

    def display_lines(self, x1, y1, x2, y2, color):
        x_plus = x1     ## all lines are evenly spaced
        y_plus = y1
        for ctr in range(7):
            self.canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill = color)
            x1 += x_plus
            x2 += x_plus
            y1 += y_plus
            y2 += y_plus

CG = CanvasGrid()
```

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
def displayHorizontal(self):
    self.canvas.create_line(50, 50, 50, 50, fill = "blue",
                            tags = "line")
```

Has no length, it starts and ends at 50 in both x and y coordinates. Why not try `0,50,128,50`.

Answer (score -1):

The `main()` function didn't include `displayHorizontal()`, which is why the horizontal lines weren't appearing.

Comment: Who knows what `main` includes? He didn't include that in his code. What he DID include was proof that he drew a line from coordinates `(50, 50)` to coordinates `(50, 50)` which is, in fact, a dot :)